# android layout doesnt fill screen leaves a padding on left right and top

Tags: android, layout

I have a relative layout which doesnt fit the whole width and height of the device and it always leaves a padding on the top , left , bottom and right.

my activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:fillViewport ="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

manifest contains

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

im a newbie to android hence , i might have tried to repost the same question which would have been answered already!

all the answers i found are either manifest change or fill_parent.. but it doesnt help me anyway.

im testing it on a nexus 4 device.

Comment: Why are you defining `padding` if you don't want any? Also, you have your height set to `wrap_content`. Also note that `fill_parent` is deprecated and `match_parent` should be used instead

Comment: i was just playing around and did some mess! fill_parent and removal of padding did the trick along with manifest changes

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Just a little advice...when you have layout issues like this, sometimes it helps to comment out anything unnecessary then gradually add things back in to see where the problem is.

Comment: cool! i do that! but was fed up with so many changes .. just to fill the content. may be because im an android beginner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the following attributes from your `<RelativeLayout>`:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Also, seeing that you ar targeting SDK 14 as a minimum, then you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as the latter has been deprecated since API 8 in favor of the former, `match_parent`.

Comment: I don't know if the original poster was like me, but creating a default Android Application Project in Eclipse adds the padding attributes above by default to the RelativeLayout in the layout file created for the project. (It may not have been the poster explicitly defining the attributes: they just came by default.) You'd have to know enough to look for those attributes in values/dimens.xml to realize that those are 16dp.